# Is there a way to make gnome3 the default session when connecting to xrdp?

Tags: gnome, xrdp

I have an Ubuntu server running gnome3 on the desktop and xrdp. When I establish an rdp session to the Ubuntu server I get a gnome classic session. Is there a way to set the default session for xrdp to gnome3? Sorry for my ignorance but I am new to this forum and a noobie. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I don't think Gnome 3 works without 3D acceleration, and I think (I don't know for sure) that 3D acceleration is not available through xrdp.

Answer (score 1):

I did it via [automatic tool](http://scarygliders.net/2012/05/23/the-scarygliders-x11rdp-o-matic-and-rdpsesconfig-hotness-upon-hotness/). First you have to run install script then configuring script.

A. (If you don't have git) Install git

> sudo apt-get install git

B. Install X11RDP-o-matic

> git clone https://github.com/scarygliders/X11RDP-o-Matic.git

C.  Enter directory

> cd X11RDP-o-Matic

D. Run the script and wait (quite long)

> sudo ./X11rdp-o-matic.sh --justdoit

E. Run configuring script

> sudo ./RDPsesconfig.sh

In one of the screens you have the possibility to choose deafult WM

Hope it helps and I understood question well :)

Comment: After adding new user you have to run again point E. again and choose desired user.